# Finding the referring url that brought a user to my site

Tags: c#, asp.net

#### Duplicate:

> [Finding previous page Url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772780/finding-previous-page-url)

---

How do I find the referring url that brought a user to my site in ASP.NET?

---

#### See Also:

> [How can I find what search terms (if any) brought a user to my site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57004/how-can-i-find-what-search-terms-if-any-brought-a-user-to-my-site)

Comment: Duplicates, among others, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/772780/finding-previous-page-url

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Request.UrlReferrer
```

But this isn't guaranteed to be correct or even exist.

Answer (score 2):

Request.UrlReferrer can be used to retrieve the previous page url from where the current page has been redirected.

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer
```

Answer (score 0):

The referer URL should be in the HTTP headers on the request.

E.g. `Uri MyUrl = Request.UrlReferrer`

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Request.UrlReferrer

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx