# Type of Request Web Client

Tags: asp.net

As identified in C # where this is requested a specific web page, I wonder if the request comes from an image `<img src="http://www.mydomain.com/default.aspx?n=123" />` or if the request is directly through an http browser, for example when the client is actually accessing the page via a browser sample: `http://www.mydomain.com/default.aspx?n=123`

Comment: There is no way to know this, sorry. This information is not part of the HTTP protocol. Why do you need to know?

Comment: Cant be done. Remember, if i request "Foo.jpg" from your website, and request "Foo.aspx" from your website, there is nothing to distinguish one as a page, and the other as a image. They are both HTTP GET's, and i have requesting a resource. There is no such thing as an "image request" in the HTTP Protocol. @John is right. Best way to understand these things is pop open fiddler.

Comment: The question is where the request is coming from a particular page, for example, I have a page that can display content or can direct the client to one .ashx depending on where this page is being requested. if requested by a web browser, then it is available to the contents page, otherwise, if requested via <img> then he directs this request for one .ashx to display only the image content and not an html client.

Answer (score 1):

See [Finding the referring url that brought a user to my site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803027/finding-the-referring-url-that-brought-a-user-to-my-site).

You'll probably get more answers if you tag your question with ASP.NET.

No, it's not completely reliable.  HTTP is in large part a cooperative protocol.  That is, there are fields there that browsers can use to identify themselves and tell you where they're coming from, but nothing forces them to do it.  The sad truth, unbelievable as it may seem, is that *people might lie to you*.  They might say they're viewing your image from your Web page, when they really aren't.  Or their browser might not tell you that it's viewing the image from your Web page.  *In general*, the `UrlReferrer` thing works, but it can be defeated.  Just as the browser identification string can be spoofed.  We do the best that we can, and call it good enough.

Comment: That is not, in fact none of these procedures is what I'm looking for. I will list the procedures that do not work with what you really want.
Response.Write(Page.PreviousPage.ToString());
Response.Write(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
Response.Write(Context.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
Response.Write(Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"].ToString);

Comment: what I'm looking for truth would be something like the behavior that identifies whether the requested url arises when starting from an image, or originates from a different browser via http.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect the `Request.UrlReferrer` to be `null` when the image src makes the request.

Comment: Yes, but it could be null for other cases, as well. It's not reliable.

Comment: in this case that does not work even when an image is on a web page means that this page has an address but will always be a reference. UrlReferrer not work for what I need, please before you answer, read the whole question. Thank you.

Comment: Please be happy that people spend their free time answering your question.